# Powershell function parameters proper use

Tags: powershell

```
            PARAM (
                [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [string]$Poolname,
                [array]$Ports = 443,
                [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [ValidateSet("ELB","ALB")]
                $Loadbalncertype,
                [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [ValidateSet("Ping","HTTPGet")]
                $HealthCheckConfigType,
                [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                [array]$LBSubnets,
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$SecGroupID,
            [int]$IdleTimeoutsec = 60,
            [bool]$SSLPassthrough = $false,
            string]$SSLCertificateName,
                [string]$HealthCheckPath,
            [string]$SSLPolicyName,
                [bool]$ConfigureProxyProtocol = $true
                )
```

In the above I would like to use Parameter $HealthCheckConfigType only if the $Loadbalncertype = ELB. I am not sure how to create this logic in Powershell function parameter section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that in the `param` definition specifically, you could use `DynamicParam` to create a dynamic parameter, but that's a lot of work and probably overkill.

The most straightforward method I can think of if you must leave `$LoadBalancerType` as a `[string]` is to use `[ValidateScript()]` like so:

```
param(
    [ValidateSet("ELB","ALB")]
    $LoadBalancerType ,

    [ValidateScript( { $LoadBalancerType -eq 'ELB' } )]
    [ValidateSet("Ping","HTTPGet")]
    $HealthCheckConfigType
)
```

This will give a crappy error message, which you could override with a well-placed `throw`:

```
[ValidateScript( { $LoadBalancerType -eq 'ELB' -or $(throw 'A better error message') } )]
```

Another option is to change your `$LoadBalancerType` parameter into separate switch parameters, and use them to define parameter sets:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSet='ALB')]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Poolname,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ALB')]
    [Switch]$ALB ,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ELB')]
    [Switch]$ELB ,

    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'ELB')
    [ValidateSet("Ping","HTTPGet")]
    $HealthCheckConfigType
)
```

This lets the parameter parser enforce this restriction, and you can see it in the automatically generated parameter sets by calling `Get-Help` on your function.

And, even though this isn't the usual way, in your case if you name the parameter sets with the names of the values you wanted, you could recreate `$LoadBalancerType` without conditionals:

```
$LoadBalancerType = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

(assuming of course, that the only possible parameter sets are load balancer names directly; be careful with this)

But if you never really needed that string value; i.e. if you were only ever going to do:

```
if ($LoadBalancerType -eq 'ALB') {

} elseif ($LoadBalancerType -eq 'ELB') {

}
```

or something like that, then you don't need to recreate it, just do:

```
if ($ALB) {

} elseif ($ELB) {

}
```

Alternatively, you don't have to do this check in the `param` block at all; you can do it in your function body, or `begin`/`process` blocks where appropriate.

Comment: Does `ValidateScript` work that way? I tried this earlier today for a function I was writing and I got some strangeness trying to access another parameter variable from the `ValidateScript` block.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest you know, I thought I remembered having issues with it too... but before I wrote the answer I made a quick POC and it seemed to work as intended.

Comment: Conversely, I rewrote my `ValidateScript` block to operate on other parameters and it's simply not working. I don't use this attribute enough though to know if I'm wrong or you are :D

Comment: @BendertheGreatest oh very interesting. What's your `$PSVersionTable` look like? And how about your function definition? Here's mine: `function ttt { [CmdletBinding()]param([ValidateSet('a','b')]$a, [ValidateScript( {$a -eq 'b'})]$b) "$a~$b" }` If I invoke `ttt -a b -b whatever` it works, if I do `ttt -a a -b whatever` it throws. If I leave off `-b` then either value of `-a` works. Does this simple example work for you?

Comment: Running 5.1, I'm up to date. Here's what I'm doing (with params only, don't have a body yet): `Param(
        [int]$Capacity,
        [ValidateScript({
            ( $Capacity -And $_.Capacity -le $Capacity ) -Or -Not $Capacity
        })]
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Collections.IEnumerable]$IEnumerable
    )` Basically if a passed-in List capacity is greater than specified capacity it should fail to validate. But this isn't the case.

Comment: Huh. Your `ValidateScript` works, mine doesn't. I'm lost as to why.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest no you don't need `ValidateSet`. In your example there's a few things tripping you up. You are trying to accept (probably) an `ArrayList` but you're accepting any enumerable, including objects like arrays and hashtables that don't even have a `.Capacity` property. But even if you passed an arraylist by pipeline, you'd have the issue that powershell will unroll it and pass each item individually to the process block. So instead you can pass it by name `-IEnumerable $myArrayList`, only to find out, that `ValidateSet` _also_ unrolls enumerables and will check against each item.

Comment: Not an ArrayList, basically this is a helper function (not complete yet, I was validating my validators as I go) to create a `System.Collections.Generic.List[T]` from an array, or create a new one with the specified type. You bring up a good point (my oversight) that `IEnumerable` does not define Capacity. Which `<blank> -le $somePositiveNumber` evaluates to $True. Thanks for helping me clear that up.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I'm struggling to think of a good workaround for you, other than to always create a brand new `ArrayList` with the desired capacity and add the items into it. `Begin { $nal = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new($Capacity) }` then `Process { if ($IEnumerable -is [System.Collections.ICollection]) { $nal.AddRange($IEnumerable) else { $nal.Add($IEnumerable) } }` (edit: or not `ArrayList`, but you get the idea)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174523/discussion-between-bender-the-greatest-and-briantist).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DynamicParam` block: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#dynamic-parameters

I don't have a ton of experience with them myself, but here is the code sample from that MS doc. You can process and add any parameters you need:

```
  function Get-Sample {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param ([String]$Name, [String]$Path)

  DynamicParam
  {
    if ($path -match ".HKLM.:")
    {
      $attributes = New-Object -Type `
        System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
      $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
      $attributes.Mandatory = $false
      $attributeCollection = New-Object `
        -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
      $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

      $dynParam1 = New-Object -Type `
        System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("dp1", [Int32],
          $attributeCollection)

      $paramDictionary = New-Object `
        -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
      $paramDictionary.Add("dp1", $dynParam1)
      return $paramDictionary
    }
  }
}
```

Another option would be to not muck with `DynamicParam` and in your code body, simply ignore `$HealthCheckConfigType` if `$LoadBalancerType` does not equal `ELB`, but if you want to use parameter validators to check this, `DynamicParam` is the answer.